# Is it possible to enable the delete confirmation on the folder contents view?

Tags: plone

When deleting an item using the action menu, there is a confirmation modal box. Is it possible to enable this for the folder contents view too? That is, when more than one item is being deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install [collective.actions.delete](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.actions.delete/0.1.5)

Product description:
`Deletion of Plone elements from the folder contents view is submitted to a confirmation form.`

Comment: I get a TypeError: Iteration over non sequence. Is this the correct buildout config? http://pastie.org/8962794

Comment: @Adripants I'll just tested `collective.actions.delete = 0.1.5` with vanilla `Plone 4.3.2`. It worked without any problems. btw. I added the package to the eggs and zcml section.